# passing dynamic parameters in script.aculo.us

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I want to pass dynamic values inside parameters of  script.aculo.us for auto suggestion in my jsp page

Below is my code where i want to get the value of checkbox and pass it to server. But in server side jsp its printing as it is ( i.e instead pf checkbox value its printing `document.getElementById("mgmtsystem").checked` )

```
<div class="auto_complete"   id="object_name_auto_complete"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

new Ajax.Autocompleter('<%=name%>', 'object_name_auto_complete', '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/component/ajax_introdata', { parameters: 'suggEnable= document.getElementById("mgmtsystem").checked' })
</script>
```

In above code i'm trying to send the value of `document.getElementById("mgmtsystem").checked` but its just passing it as same instead its value

Comment: `document.getElementById("mgmtsystem").checked ` would return only the `true`/`false` in case of checked status.

Comment: Yes. I just want to pass that true/false value to server but somehow its not resolving true/false value and instead its sending the value as document.getElementById("mgmtsystem").checked

Comment: According to `w3 Schools` it only returns the true/false. Can you past the `mgmtsystem` HTML so can have some idea.

Comment: I just put the relavent code in http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/emZrJ/

Comment: take a look at this. this is so simple. http://jsfiddle.net/emZrJ/2/

Comment: I want to pass this true/false value to server using scriptaculos autocompleter in parameters  but i couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you copied your javascript into the question as it is on your code - this is why

This code does not let `document.getElementById(....)` get evaluated and treats it as a string

```
{ parameters: 'suggEnable= document.getElementById("mgmtsystem").checked' }
```

Try this

```
{ parameters: 'suggEnable='+document.getElementById("mgmtsystem").checked }
```

Or better yet use the utility methods built in to PrototypeJS

```
{ parameters: 'suggEnable='+$("mgmtsystem").checked }
```

Comment: I checked but still its passing the string . Instead i used callback: function in scriptaculos and there i had appended the value dynamically .